# People Dataset for 3D instance segmentation

Tags: data-request, images

I have multiple kinect cameras that I use to make a pointcloud of the scene. I want to perform Instance segmentation on the scene which will involve people. But I need a dataset for that, all the datasets I have looked at seem to be for outdoors or indoors but with no people in them. (like [scannet](http://www.scan-net.org/))

Are there any multiview RGB-D datasets available that would involve people ? something like scannet but with people in it.